# borg mount returns “Mountpoint must be a writable directory”

Tags: linux, fedora, mount, backup

What is the proper way to mount a borg backup? Tried mounting backup from my user account by:

```
borg mount /my/borg/backup/source /mnt/myborg/backup
```

Returns this error:

```
/mnt/myborg/backup: Mountpoint must be a writable directory
```

Put the following into /etc/fstab but still getting same error.

```
/my/borg/backup/source   /mnt/myborg/backup     fuse.borgfs defaults,noauto,user    0 0
```

Comment: Check the permissions on `/mnt/myborg/backup`. Does the user running `borg` have write access there?

Comment: 'ls -l /mnt/myborg/backup' displays
'ls: cannot access '/mnt/borg': No such file or directory'

Comment: There seems to be a mixup, both paths in your command do not match... you have `/my/borg`, `/mnt/myborg` and now `/mnt/borg`... :-( Make sure to create the mountpoint `/mnt/myborg/backup` before using it.